# First-differences regression of a cointegrating system: forecasting and interpretation

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cointegration, unit-root, differences

I am working with a time series regression. In particular, both my dependent and independent variables are I(1) and they are co-integrated. I was wondering the following:

If I run a regression with first differences, can I use it to forecast and how do I interpret the coefficient results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it for **forecasting**, but your model will be missing the error correction term. You could argue you are omitting it deliberately because estimating it would add more noise than signal and thus bring the forecast accuracy down, but that is a speculation. You could try including the error correction term and seeing whether that helps w.r.t. forecast accuracy.

**Interpreting** a model with a missing term would be messy as the effects of the missing term will be subsumed into the remaining terms.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Comment: @Boom, you are welcome!